# Graph API filter

Tags: linq, azure-ad-graph-api

how to recreate this LINQ:

```
applications.Where(x => x.Owners.Any(y=>y.Id == "user_object_id"));
```

to Graph API filter string, something like

```
graphServiceClient.Applications.Request().Filter("Owners/any(x:x/Id eq 'user_object_id'")).GetAsync();
```

Comment: What is this query trying to get? Users with the objectID?

Comment: Applications where owner's id is provided user object id. Actually I need to find applications which I own.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) I highly recommend it to test queries. You can use it on your own data.

For your query I would start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with `GET /applications`

From there you can filter with something like displayName or in your case, userID:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?$filter=startswith(displayName, 'a')&$count=true&$top=1&$orderby=displayName
```

ConsistencyLevel: eventual

Please let me know if you have any questions or are stuck and I can help you further!

Best,
James